# Unity Deserializing from server

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

I have been trying for a couple hours to deserialize info from my server for our high score system. However I am getting an error:

> ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.

This is how I am deserializing (`scores` is of type Scores):

```
public void Deserialize()
{
    Debug.Log("From Server is ::::: -----> " + FromServer);
    scores = JsonUtility.FromJson<Scores> (FromServer);
}
```

This is my Json info which is generated by my server. What am I doing wrong?

```
 [
    {
        "ScoreID": "8",
        "GoogleID": "asasda",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "11",
        "GoogleID": "kjjahushcjkasjkcajskndas",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "10",
        "GoogleID": "aakhskjbjkabsjjkasd",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "9",
        "GoogleID": "mnbabksgkajsd",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "13",
        "GoogleID": "kajiuskabkjshdkhausd",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "7",
        "GoogleID": "asasdas,mgkhgjhbhjaf",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "6",
        "GoogleID": "ss",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "5",
        "GoogleID": "kljkuasjkba",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "4",
        "GoogleID": "asdadasdasdasdw",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "3",
        "GoogleID": "asdadsasd",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "2",
        "GoogleID": "kbaskjkjsbnkjas",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "12",
        "GoogleID": "lahaushyuiahkjsjksd",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "1",
        "GoogleID": "254asdasd54a5s1das2d1as54d",
        "Score": "259"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "14",
        "GoogleID": "kjaskjhjkahsjkdnjkasd",
        "Score": "6859"
    }
]
```

and these are the classes I'm trying to serialize into:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LeaderBoardEntries
{
    public int ScoreID;
    public string GoogleID;
    public int Score;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Scores
{
    public List<LeaderBoardEntries> scores;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with an `array` instead of a `List` like this: `public LeaderBoardEntries[] scores;`

Comment: Maybe your values should be typed and not a string ? For example `"ScoreID": "5"` should be `"ScoreID": 5`

Comment: Sorry mate how do you mean? On my server they are type int, google id is type varchar.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only have 1 object in the .json file to be able to deserialize it via `JsonUtility`. Your .json is not an object, it's an array of objects. It should be in this format:

```
{
    scores: [
    {
        "ScoreID": "8",
        "GoogleID": "asasda",
        "Score": "258"
    },
    {
        "ScoreID": "11",
        "GoogleID": "kjjahushcjkasjkcajskndas",
        "Score": "258"
    }
    ]
}
```

this .json string can be deserialized into a `Scores` object.

I agree Unity should make their documentation a little more clear. They need to emphasize that you can deserialize .json files representing only 1 object.

Comment: Thanks for that but it doesnt seem to work, 

scores = JsonUtility.FromJson<Scores> ("{\"scores\": " + FromServer + "}");

I added the beginning string to this as my server does not of course out put this, i no longer get any errors but i also do not get my class filled with info from the json

Comment: Got it working was a simple typo. Thank you!