# Json To Array exeption in Unity 2018 exeption when parse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I`m using JsonHelper (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111) and set all in my program

UserInfo.cs

```
[Serializable]
public class UserInfo : MonoBehaviour {
    public string number;
    public string name;
}
```

And when I call  `UserInfo[] list = JsonHelper.FromJson<UserInfo>(www.downloadHandler.text);`, I see

> ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.

Please help me.
Json
`[{"number":0,"name":"Bulbasaur"},{"number":1,"name":"Ivysaur"},{"number":2,"name":"Venusaur"},{"number":3,"name":"Charmander"},{"number":4,"name":"Charmeleon"},{"number":5,"name":"Charizard"},{"number":6,"name":"Squirtle"}]`

Comment: I'd guess this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43233724. If not, can you please show us the JSON you're trying to deserialize? (i.e. please edit an example into the question)

Comment: I`m edit. Add json

Comment: See the example class from the dup. It doesn't inherit from MonoBehaviour. You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the wrapper class below...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint = false)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
string JSONToParse = "{\"Items\":" + www.downloadHandler.text + "}";
UserInfo[] list = JsonHelper.FromJson<UserInfo>(JSONToParse);
```

Why?

```
"{\"Items\":"
```

must match the name of the Array variable

```
public T[] Items;
```

EDIT:

Found your problem. **Remove** "MonoBehaviour" as inheritance from UserInfo. That should fix it. The serializer cannot serialize classes that inherit from monobehaviour, component, scriptableobject etc. Only plain classes (models) work.

```
[Serializable]
public class UserInfo 
{
    public string number;
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: I am try but not work i have json: `[{"number":0,"name":"Bulbasaur"},{"number":1,"name":"Ivysaur"},{"number":2,"name":"Venusaur"},{"number":3,"name":"Charmander"},{"number":4,"name":"Charmeleon"},{"number":5,"name":"Charizard"},{"number":6,"name":"Squirtle"}]` and try return first but unity say null ((

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code containing the call to the JsonHelper?

Comment: Have you verified that you get a reponse by calling Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text)   ?

Comment: Yes I am check. He load `[{"number":0,"name":"Bulbasaur"},{"number":1,"name":"Ivysaur"},{"number":2,"name":"Venusaur"},{"number":3,"name":"Charmander"},{"number":4,"name":"Charmeleon"},{"number":5,"name":"Charizard"},{"number":6,"name":"Squirtle"}]`

Comment: See my latest edit for the solution

Comment: Thenks Its work